# Facebook like button counter reset

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have problems with counter of facebook like button. I've tried to use iframe and XFBML, the results were the same.
When I click the button, the counter appears with the right value "1", on facebook account page appears the right like post (with image, descriptoin etc.). But if I refresh the page, where the button is, the counter on it is disappered and its value became "0" again. For example: http://biletoid.ru/event/?event_id=25

How can I solve that problem?

Meta:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://storage.biletoid.ru/0000/0000/0000/0325/47.jpg" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Лучшая рок-группа последних 30 лет приезжает в Сербию. Стоимость перелета от 6969 руб. Дата проведения: 08.05.2012." />
<meta property="og:title" content="Metallica в Белграде" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:locale" content="ru_RU" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://biletoid.ru/event/?event_id=25" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Biletoid"/>
```

Script:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Html:

```
<fb:like href="<?php echo 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>" send="false" layout="button_count" width="95" height="19" show_faces="true" action="like"></fb:like>
```

Comment: url is only one for each page. counter is reset even if I reload page with F5.

Comment: I'm stumped. Took a look at your site. Pressing the like button caused the count to go up, it appears on my feed. But I refresh the page and the count disappears. However I did notice you have show_faces="true". Try taking that out. It may be causing the problem due to the layout you chose.

Comment: I've already tried it. Took it out and set as "false". There is no result, count always disappears.

Comment: I've got the same issue and no clues

Answer (score 1):

1.
I went to

```
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/
```

I entered your page http://biletoid.ru/event/?event_id=25 as the like url.

I clicked the like url generated. A red error text is shown. Click on the red error text.

Then, a pop-up showed the error:

The page failed to provide a valid list of administrators. It needs to specify the administrators using either a "fb:app_id" meta tag, or using a "fb:admins" meta tag to specify a comma-delimited list of Facebook users.

So you should add one of these:

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="<YOUR FACEBOOK APP ID>"/>
```

OR

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="<ADMIN's FACEBOOK USER ID>"/>
```

Before your currently existing open graph tags.

`<YOUR FACEBOOK APP ID>` is a numeric id. For example,

```
http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=4
```

is mark zuckerburg, so 4 is mark's facebook user id. So you need to find your facebook user id. To find your own facebook user id - log into facebook with your account and find the profile link on the top right corner. The id= is your facebook user id.

`<ADMIN's FACEBOOK USER ID>` is also a numeric id. A Facebook App can be added at

```
https://developers.facebook.com/apps
```

and at there you obtain the Facebook App ID for your facebook application can be added at your facebook application configuration page.

2.
So you need to have something like,

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="<your facebook application id>" id="fbapp_id"/>
```

OR

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="<ADMIN's FACEBOOK USER ID>"/>
```

PLUS

```
<meta property="og:type" content="<video>" id="ogtype"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="<title>" id="ogtitle"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="<image>" id="ogimage1"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="<like description>" id="ogdescription"/>
<meta property="og:determiner" content="a" id="ogdeterminer"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="<your like page url>" id="ogurl"/>
```

3.
To find out whether your facebook open graph tags are done correctly, put your url into:

```
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug
```